# Can't get VLOOKUP working with roster spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have an Excel spreadsheet set up as a roster.  The way the roster is setup is for the ease of the person creating the rotation.  This roster is not easy to read for the staff.

```
                Mon     Tues    Wed     Thurs   Fri     Sat
0600-1430 NSH   Dennis  Mike    Dennis  Dennis  Dennis  Jim
0600-1430 WTH   Mike    Dennis  Mike    Mike    Mike    Raj
0700-1530 NSH   Blair   Blair   Blair   Blair   Blair
```

I am trying to use `VLOOKUP` to enter in another sheet all a specific persons shifts on one line.  For example:

```
       Mon              Tues            Wed             Thurs           Fri
Mike   0600-1430 WTH    0600-1430 NSH   0600-1430 WTH   0600-1430 WTH   0600-1430 WTH
Dennis 0600-1430 NSH    0600-1430 WTH   0600-1430 NSH   0600-1430 NSH   0600-1430 NSH
Blair  0700-1530 NSH    0700-1530 NSH   0700-1530 NSH   0700-1530 NSH   0700-1530 NSH
```

So I want the `VLOOKUP` to search "Dennis" in the "Mon" column (column B).  And when it finds "Dennis", I want it to return the shift time and location (column A).

I have tried the following, but it doesn't return the correct value.

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,A3:B14,1)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second table in your question has the days in row 1 and the names in column J, and if your first table starts in A1, you can use this in cell K2, copy down and to the right

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MATCH($J2,B$1:B$4,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked a treat. I will be adding a IFNA statement to the front of it, but it has done what i was hoping for.  Thanks for your quick help...